# Selenium- Number of returned windows is unexpected in IE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently automating an application based on Java platform using selenium + Cucumber + Internet Explorer and is facing some challenges. I need some expert help from this group on the issues.

Problem Description - Upon clicking a link on the page, new browser get opened.  GetWindowHandles is returning value 3 irrespective of number of browser opened by WebDriver. I have used Click() on the link & tried getWindowHandles()

Environment used – Selenium WebDriver – 2.43.0 IEDriverServer.exe - Win32 Windows 7 Internet Explorer 11.0

Note – it is working fine on Firefox & Chrome, this issue is happening on IE only.

Comment: Can you please share your web driver code?

Comment: public void navigateTo(String Name) throws Throwable {

        switch (Name) {
            case "Feedback":
                footContainer.Link_ClickHere.click();
                feedback = new Feedback(driver);
                break;

        }

    }

After click then it return to feedback screen. 

Report.Step(driver.getWindowHandles().size() == 2, driver.getWindowHandles().size() == 2 ? "New page is opened" : "New page isn't opened", driver.getWindowHandles().size() != 2);

Comment: Got solution for the above problem.. use the javascript executor  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",footContainer.Link_ClickHere.getWrappedElement());